# PostgresSQL, funciòn para actualizar datos de tabla

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Estoy tratando de crear un funcion que me permita actualizar los datos de un client de la tabla "clients"(clientid,name,userid), la funcion toma como parametros el id del client y el id del usuario al cual esta asignado el client, lo que tiene que hacer es actualizar el userid de un client.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateclient_uid(clientid text,userid text)   RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE  clients
    SET userid = '@userid', 
    WHERE clientid = '@clientid'; 
END;
$BODY$   
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE   
COST 100; 
ALTER FUNCTION updateclient_uid(text, text)   
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Al darle "Execute query" recibo un error de syntaxis cerca de "WHERE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, el problema fue asi de simple: en`'@userid',` la coma esta demas y esto no le gustaba al compilador, eliminando la coma soluciono el problema.